# Finding a cluster of words and replacing them with one word

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am parsing a string such as

```
Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left]
```

I want to find multiple patterns of [Left][Left] and replace them so the output becomes

```
Hello[Left x 2]This is a test string[Left x 4]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is `[Left]` a single keystroke (pressing the keyboard's left arrow key), or text that appears in the string?

Comment: Text that appears in the string.

Comment: I have an idea of using split string and foreach loop. If you can figured it out , fine. If not , I would answer this in approx~1 hour.

Comment: You might find some inspiration in the traditional compression methods, like [LZ77](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that is a bit shorter.

```
var word = "Left";
var source = "Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left]";
var replaceRegex = new Regex("(\\[" + word + "\\])\\1+");
var result = replaceRegex.Replace(source, delegate(Match m)
{
    return string.Format("[{0} x {1}]"
              , word
              , m.Groups[0].ToString().Length / m.Groups[1].ToString().Length);
});
```

What happens is that I use the regular expression element `\n` where n references the nth captured group. Then a simple `MatchEvaluator` lets us count how many instances of the word exist. I use the length of the whole matched group (`m.Groups[0]`) divided by the length of the captured group (`m.Groups[1]`) but you may want to change this computation.

You can even capture multiple words, different words, etc... Tweaking the regular expression will let you catch spaces between repeating words, etc...

**EDIT:** and here is a version where the brackets are integrated into the "word" since i didn't like having the brackets littering the code

```
var word = "[Left]";
var compressedWord = "[Left x {0}]";
var source = "Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left]";
var replaceRegex = new Regex("(" + Regex.Escape(word) + ")\\1+");
var result = replaceRegex.Replace(source, delegate(Match m)
{
    return string.Format(compressedWord
              , m.Groups[0].ToString().Length / m.Groups[1].ToString().Length);
});
```

Comment: Cool! The MatchEvaluator was actually what I was grasping for. In perl I would have used something similar: `$text =~ s!((?:\[Left\]){2,})!sprintf("[Left x %d]", length($1)/6)!ge;`

Comment: As always in .Net the way to do something is hidden in the methods alternative signatures :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
String input = "Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left]";
MatchCollection c = Regex.Matches(input, "(?:\\[Left\\])+");
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
int start = 0;
foreach (Match m in c)
{
    output.Append(input.Substring(start, m.Index - start));
    output.AppendFormat("[Left x {0}]", m.Length / 6);
    start = m.Index + m.Length;
}
output.Append(input.Substring(start));
Console.Write(output.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should capture whatever is between [] and count occurrences that are the same. It'll match anything in brackets and group them if they are neighbors and contain the same text.

```
var data = @"Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left][Left]"; // Outputs: Hello[Left x 2]This is a test string[Left x 5]
//data = @"Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Right][Right][Left]"; // Outputs: Hello[Left x 2]This is a test string[Left x 2][Right x 2][Left]

var matches = new Queue<Match>(Regex.Matches(data, @"\[([^]]+?)\]").Cast<Match>());
var builder = new StringBuilder();

var position = 0;
while (matches.Count > 0)
{
    var start = matches.Dequeue();
    var end = start;
    var count = 1;

    while (matches.Count > 0 && start.Value.Equals(matches.Peek().Value) && (end.Index + end.Length) == matches.Peek().Index)
    {
        end = matches.Dequeue();
        count++;
    }

    if (start.Index > position)
    {
        builder.Append(data.Substring(position, start.Index - position)); // Not matched text
    }

    if (count > 1)
    {
        builder.Append(String.Format("[{0} x {1}]", start.Groups[1], count)); // Matched duplicates
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append(start.Value);  // Matched solo so skipping " x 1"
    }

    position = end.Index + end.Length;
}

var processed = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this version works for you

```
        var relacedText = "Hello[Left][Left]This is a test string[Left][Left][Left][Left]".Replace("[Left]", "#");
        var template = "[Left x {0}]";
        var finalString = "";
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var c in relacedText)
        {
            if (c == '#')
            {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                finalString += string.Format(template, counter);
                counter = 0;
            }
            finalString += c;

        }
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            finalString += string.Format(template, counter);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. check first `if` in `foreach` loop.

Comment: `if c == "#"` is string contain # symbol?

Comment: @Muhammad, I didn't get you.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @krisku, I don't see a reason why this doesn't work. It works for me. You can try. What did you find bogus? Yes the code has the limitation that the char that you choose as a replacement for the [Left] should not occur in the string itself. Other than that ...hmmmm

Comment: Sorry, I failed to scroll the code to the right so I did not see the `Replace("[Left]","#")` at the end of the line. With that it actually works, but I would not call it especially efficient to iterate through the string one character at a time. You would get terrible performance for long input, and your code would fail if the input string contains `#` characters..

Comment: @krisku, Yes  string Replace can be inefficient , but you didn't complain about that. Iterating each char at a time??...How does Regex do comparison?? running a [NFA ENGINE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does all the iterations for you and many more iterations that you could have escaped. My knowledge tells me when you find performance issues with Regex you relegate to string manipulation.